# Working out LED specs

Tags: led, pcb

I've got a D-Link DGS 1210-08P that I'm transplanting from its original enclosure into a custom enclosure. I need to put in some custom LEDs to replace the existing ones, as the position won't work in the new enclosure.

What is the best way to "reverse engineer" the LEDs? From my brief inspection, it looks like the LEDs are controlled by the 74HC164D shift register, which might help narrow the search down.

[image: PCB]

The other thing that might help is knowing whether the 4 by 4 LED matrix is a custom part, or something that is off-the-shelf? I've tried searching, but can't really see anything similar.

[image: LED Housing]

Comment: Please trace out how the original LEDs were connected to the 74HC164D and draw a schematic.

Comment: It just looks like they're using the shift register outputs with a current limiting resistor to drive each LED.  To winny's point if you just draw out the schematic with the resistor values you'll get what you need which shouldn't be too difficult as the majority of the traces appear to be on the top layer.

Comment: @circularrecursion Also, note that the ten transparant LEDs are bicolor (Amber/Green) so they will probably have three leads each.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to remove them anyway, to wire up new LEDs, then the easiest solution is going to be to unsolder the LED array from the board.

Then probe around the terminals of the LED block with a voltage limited, current limited power supply.  I'd recommend about 3.3 to 5V and a limit of 20mA or less.  If you don't have a current limited supply, stick a 100 ohm resistor in series, which should limit the current to less than 5mA.

I can only see 8 connections, which suggests a 4x4 array.

Whatever it is, it shouldn't take long to work out which pins supply which LED, and whay the polarity is (i.e. which pins are anodes or cathodes).